# What property of modular arithmetic is being used in equation $3 + 2 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 3 + 2 \cdot 2 \pmod5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Was looking for a hint of what kind of property of modular arithmetic is used in this equation. In particular how did  $  3^{-1}$ become $2$?

\begin{align*}
3 + 2 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 3 + 2 \cdot 2 \pmod5 \\
\
\end{align*}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $3^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod5$.  That's because $2\cdot 3\equiv 6\equiv 1\pmod5$.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to view this modular congruence as an equation over the finite field $\Bbb F_5$. Then it is just the equation $2\cdot 3=1$, so $2$ and $3$ are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^{-1}$ by definition is the unique multiplicative inverse to $3$.
We compute that $3*2 = 6 = 1 (mod 5)$, so 2 is this inverse called '$3^{-1}$'.

Does this work?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.